# Why do blur event not working?

Tags: javascript

This are the code that I currently have:

```
var interval;

function printPageState() {
    console.log("active");
}

window.onfocus = function() {
    console.log("focus");
    clearInterval(interval);

    interval = setInterval(printPageState, 2000);
};

window.onblur = function() {
    console.log("blur");
    clearInterval(interval);
};

window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log("scroll");
    if (!document.hasFocus())
        document.getElementById("some-id").focus();

    clearInterval(interval);

    interval = setInterval(printPageState, 2000);
};
```

I'm  attempting to create a user attention checker/page-pinging like functionality. the checker currently has an event handler for blur, focus, and scroll event.

And I'm having the problem that was stated above when the following stuff are met.

- Your browser had some viewable part on the browser view port which make it possible to scroll even if the page was not in focus.
- The page was out of focus and or blur event was already fired.

I want to stop the interval but the blur event was not firing anymore as the browser isn't focus so I tried to force the focus state on one of the element but no locky it wasn't working.

Do the following issue to replicate the issue:

- Open the page in minimized browser > then focus out the page.
- Scroll on the visible browser view port but do not click (which won't make focus state true).

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to now on which browser(s) this does happen.

Comment: I've happen to test it on chrome and firefox . it happens on both so Im guessing that this will also happen in IE aswell.

Comment: I'm guessing wildly the problem isn't the `blur` event, but the fact that timers will pause when you leave that browser window

Comment: no, that was the exact contrary of what is happening .. when I scroll without focus of the browser the timers will begin again which I wanted to stop when I click on the other tab or any stuff not related to the page.